# Play a notification sound when inbox item appears

Tags: feature-request

I like to leave my StackExchange and email tabs open on my web browser while I work.

When I get an email, it makes a sound, so I instinctively check my email straight away.

If StackExchange sites made a sound when I received a new item in my inbox, I would benefit from it, because:

- I would be able to view my messages as soon as they appear, thus I am able to respond more promptly.
- I would not have to unnecessarily view the tab if I do not have any new items in my inbox.

Comment: There would have to be an option to this on or off. Not everyone wants a *ding* going off every few mins.

Comment: Also, have you seen [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle)?

Comment: @Sam An option to turn it off would be a necessity, I agree. And perhaps *ding* just the once until the user views their notifications. Personally, not a fan of extensions.

Comment: That would definitely be more more helpful.

Comment: As an added optional extra: I would also benefit from a *different* sound if I get a new item in my achievements.

Comment: The workaround is to install the android app, if your phone can support it.

Comment: There are many options already available at http://stackapps.com/.

Comment: Related: [Can you add optional desktop notifications for new inbox items?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178576)

Comment: You should probably prioritize SE notifications below emails while you're at work...

Comment: @MartijnPieters My point is: a notification tone is something to consider implementing into the core site, i.e. without apps or add-ons.

Comment: @rybo111: I understand that, but that doesn't mean that current workarounds are not perfectly acceptable.